# How to determine if the two out-of-order long-strings arrays are exactly equal?

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

There are two out-of-order strings  arrays, which contain multiple very long strings that may be repeated. How to determine if the two arrays are exactly equal?

Example:

```
[“abc”, "abc", "bcd", "efg"] ==  ["bcd", "efg", “abc”, "abc"]
```

The easiest way I can think of is to compare two arrays after sorting.

But when each string in the array is very long, it is time consuming to perform string comparisons each time. Is there any way to improve it?

```
 let array1 = ["aaa...(100 a)...aa", "bbb...(100 b)... bbb", "ccc...(100c) ...c", ....]
 let array2 = ["bbb...(100 b)... bbb", "aaa...(100 a)...aa", "ccc...(100c) ...c", ....]
```

You can use any language to solve, but you can't use the functions in the library to directly compare the arrays for equality.

Comment: In which language you are trying to do?

Comment: create a `Counter()` object during iteration of the arrays and compare them. Typically, this be a hash of each word and its associated appearance count. Will work in O(n) time and space.

Comment: C/C++ or Java, It is best not to use language built-in array comparison functions.

Comment: Sorry I posted my answer in Javascript I saw your message late but logic will remain same in Java also

Comment: Please give the question relevant language tags. If needed throw out `algorithm` + `sorting`, those are quite useless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If in Python:

```
import collections
def areItersEqual(a1, a2):    
    return collections.Counter(a1) == collections.Counter(a2)

>>> a1 = [“abc”, "abc", "bcd", "efg"] 
>>> a2 = ["bcd", "efg", “abc”, "abc"] 
>>> assert areItersEqual(a1,a2) is True
True
```

With this the upper bounds of time and space are O(m+n) as opposed to O(n logn) + O(m logm) time with sorting.

This can be written without `Counter()` too:

```
def areItersEqual(a1, a2):
    c = {}
    for word in a1:
        if word in c:
            c[word] += 1
        else:
            c[word] = 0

    for word in a2:
        if word in c:
            c[word] -= 1
        else:
            return False
return not(bool([v for k,v in c.items() if v!=0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting the strings, you could take the hash of each string and compare those. (These you may want to sort.)

However this still requires you to compare the strings directly if the hashes are equal, since hash collisions could yield false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Just check below code with Javascript :)

```
var a1 = ["abc", "abc", "bcd", "efg"];
var a2 = ["bcd", "efg", "abc", "abc"]
var allIndexExist = true;
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    var index = a2.indexOf(a1[i]);
    if (index == -1) {
        allIndexExist = false;
        break;
    } else {
        a2.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
if (a2.length > 0 || !allIndexExist) {
    console.log("Array is not equal");
} else {
    console.log("Array is equal");
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` still has to enumerate the entire array and perform multiple string comparisons. This should still be an O(n^2). But it's also a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
  func test() -> Bool {
    var a1 = ["abc", "abc", "bcd", "efg"]
    var a2 = ["bcd", "efg", "abc", "abc"]
    if a1.count != a2.count {
       return false
    }
    var temp = [String: Int]()

    for ele in a1 {
        if let count = temp[ele] {  //  if temp contain key
            temp[ele] = count + 1
        } else {
            temp[ele] = 1
        }
    }

    for ele in a2 {
        if let count = temp[ele] { //  if temp contain key 
           if count == 0 {
              return false
           } else if count == 1 {
              temp[ele] = nil
           } else {
              temp[ele] = count - 1
           }           
        } else {
           return false
        }
    }
    return temp.count == 0
}

print(test())
```

This function can only be solved by enumerating two arrays. O(n)